# Instant App Showing Issues While Uploading to Production

Tags: android, google-play, release, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

I have created an instant app and uploaded successfully to internal test track of **Play Store**. and it is working fine there. but when I try to move it to production it shows the below error

[image]

Regarding the first error

> buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
>   minSdkVersion = 19
>   compileSdkVersion = 27
>   targetSdkVersion = 27

Which is same for both instant app and production apk. but still I am getting this error.

Regarding the second error here is my permission list

> package: name='my-package-name' versionCode='versionCode'
>   versionName='my-version-name' sdkVersion:'19' targetSdkVersion:'27'
>   uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'

There is no permission added as mentioned in the error. Can some one help me to figure out this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it corrected !!

1 - The error message is not correct actually, the issue was due to **minSdk**, instant app starts support from API 21, making minSdk to 21 fixed that issue

2 - The instant app's **manifest permission** should be same as **manifest of app**. I have added all the permissions used in apk to instant app, and that also resolved.